# How to mock expo-camera requestCameraPermissionsAsync() response?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo-camera

I am trying to do a unit test to one of my react native components.
One scenario requires me to mock `expo-camera` [requestCameraPermissionsAsync()](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#camerarequestpermissionsasync) method but don't know how. What I'm trying to do is to mock the status to always have the `granted` value.

Initial approach, below:

```
jest.mock('expo-camera', () => {
  const PermissionsCamera = jest.requireActual('expo-camera');

  return {
    ...PermissionsCamera,
    requestCameraPermissionsAsync: () =>
      new Promise(resolve => resolve({granted: true, status: 'granted'})),
  };
});
```

But that doesn't work. Need help, is there something wrong with the code above? Thank you

Update:
How I implemented in the component:

```
import {Camera} from 'expo-camera'

useEffect(() => {
 (async () => {
   const {status} = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
   // additional logic when status is equal to 'granted'
 })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023 answer**

I was struggling —the same as you— and then I realized `Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()` is Deprecated.

I ended up [using the hook useCameraPermissions](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#usecamerapermissionsoptions)

and using the last version of `expo` and `jest-expo`

```
"expo": "^48.0.6",
"jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to mock with the new `useCameraPermissions` hook to request permission

```
jest.mock('expo-camera', () => {

    const actual = jest.requireActual('expo-camera')

    const camera = actual.Camera

    camera.useCameraPermissions = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {

        const requestPermission = () => {
            console.log('request permission called')
            return Promise.resolve({ status: 'granted' })
        }

        const permission = '' // set the value you want

        return [
            permission, 
            requestPermission
          
        ]
    })

    console.log('camera', camera)

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...actual,
        Camera: camera
    }

})
```